# Can't get backbone events to fire; render models to more than one location

Tags: backbone.js

I can't seem to get events to fire.

Here's the multiple and the single views:

Single:

```
PartyView =  Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'span',
className: 'aParty',
senderTemplate: _.template($('#senderTemplate').html()),
recipientTemplate: _.template($('#recipientTemplate').html()),
render: function () {
if (this.model.get("isSender")=="1")
    $("#senders").append(this.senderTemplate(this.model.toJSON()))
else
    $("#recipients").append(this.recipientTemplate(this.model.toJSON()))
},
events: {
    "click .delete":"deleteParty",
    'click #recipients': "sayhi"
},
sayhi : function () { console.log ("hi"); },
deleteParty:function () {
    this.model.destroy();
    this.remove();
}
})
```

Multiple:

```
PartiesView = Backbone.View.extend({
className: "partiesView",
senderTemplate: _.template($('#senderTemplate').html()),
recipientTemplate: _.template($('#recipientTemplate').html()),
render: function(eventName) {
    $("#senders").empty();
    $("#recipients").empty();
  _.each(this.model.models, function(party){
      var partyview = new PartyView ({ model: party })
      partyview.render();
  }, this);

  return this;
},
events : {
'click #recipients': "sayhi"
},
sayhi : function () { console.log ("hi"); }
});
```

I get no console errors and everything renders just fine.  I just can't get the sayhi or delete events to fire though.  I suspect its most closely related to [events getting lost in templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212287/backbone-view-event-not-firing-not-sure-why?rq=1) and [this similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037303/backbone-events-not-firing-general-feedback-on-use-of-the-framework), but really I've been trying to figure it out for hours now.  Any guidance would be appreciated!!

EDIT 1:

Here's the templates:

```
<script type='text/template' id='senderTemplate'>
<span class='greenbubble'><%= email%>&nbsp;<button class='delete'>x</button></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</script>

<script type='text/template' id='recipientTemplate'>
<span class='lightbluebubble'><%= email%>&nbsp;<button class='delete'>x</button></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</script>
```

EDIT 2:

`#senders` and `#recipients` are currently in the HTML

```
<div id='partiesView'>
Senders:<span id='senders'></span><BR>
Recipients:<span id='recipients'></span>
</div>
```

EDIT 3:

A final working version in a fiddle!!

[Final version in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkasson/SprKn/45/)

Comment: On the surface the `delete` wiring looks ok; would you setup a fiddle so we can experiment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm suspicious of the `#recipients` reference. A View's `events` property only delegates to items that are inside the view's `el`, and I'm not seeing `#recipients` anywhere in any of your views. If `#recipients` is outside both of these views, it won't fire.

*edits based on the comments*

You shouldn't be doing this sort of thing:

```
$("#senders").append(this.senderTemplate(this.model.toJSON()))
```

because you're probably modifying elements outside the view's `$el`. Instead, do this:

```
this.$("#senders").append(this.senderTemplate(this.model.toJSON()))
```

All elements you wish to bind to should be contained inside the view's `$el`. If they're not, they won't bind properly. That's probably the root cause of all your bindings, not just the `#recipients`.

Comment: I'd be suspicious of `#senders` as well. A view should almost never mess with any part of the DOM other than its own `el` and the view should almost always create and completely control its own `el`.

Comment: Ahhh, I see.  Then is it possible to render models to different spots if they were within the Collection's View?  i.e. have `partiesView` as the collection's `el` and have models render to either `#senders` or `#recipients` depending on which kind of model it is?

Comment: Yeah, normally you'd have a view with `#partiesView` as its `el` and then you could listen for events like `'click #senders .delete'` in that view and work say things like [`this.$('#senders').append(...)`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) to modify the HTML. You'll have a better time if your views are completely self-contained and they use `this.$()` instead of `$()` to manipulate their internals.

Comment: Updated this answer to incorporate these insights. Y'all are exactly right.

Comment: Chris and mu, thanks for the input!! Chris, I didn't have to go with `this.$("#senders")`, but you were definitely in the right direction.  I needed the model view to render it to an `el` and provide it up to the collection view to append into the right spot.
I put together a fiddle that has the completed version. See link in question.

Comment: Glad to help. For what it's worth, the `this.$` shortcut is actually faster because it limits the scope of jQuery's search to the view's `$el`, rather than the entire DOM. I recommend using it :)