# How to attach backbone collections to specific html elements without hardcoding?

Tags: html, node.js, backbone.js

I'm trying to figure out how to split my events into days (mon-sun).

Within my collection, I'm trying to parse the events based upon their date like thus

```
var eventCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.render);
    },
    tagName: "div",
    className: "events",
    render: function(){
        var Monday = new eventDayCollectionView();
        var Tuesday;
        var Wednesday;
        var Thursday;
        var Friday;
        var Saturday;
        var Sunday;
        this.collection.each(function(eventItem) {
            var searchDate = eventItem.get('searchDate');
            if (date < 1)
             monday.add(eventItem)
            else if (date < 2)
            tuesday.add(eventItem)

        }, this);
for Monday
     append the monday objects to monday div
for Tuesday
     append the tuesday objects to tuesday div
            return this;
        }
    });
```

Above is the pseudocode, however, this entire collection is being set as the html of a div called events. But instead, I want to append the monday-sunday events to separate divs. However, is this the best way to go about approaching it? Because I want to expand this not just to a week, but to a month, and it seems like an awful lot of hardcoding. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I did something just like this, although only for two `<div>`s. I don't think it was programmatic allocation to the `<div>`s, but that shouldn't be too hard.

See this: [Can't get backbone events to fire; render models to more than one location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686384/cant-get-backbone-events-to-fire-render-models-to-more-than-one-location)

There's some decent discussion there.